# How to install Python Package for global use by all users (incl. www-data)

Tags: php, python, apache, shell, pip

I thought I throw together a little dirty script on our server (Ubuntu 16.04) that gives me some plain text output from Python.

I want to call the script like this from PHP (I know there should be some escaping done, but it's just a test currently):

```
<?php
$command = '/usr/local/bin/script.py';
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;
?>
```

This is `script.py` owned by www-data mode `774`

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import CoolProp.CoolProp as CP
import argparse
print('Hallo Welt')
```

If I comment out the `CoolProp` import it works. But somehow the package cannot be reached by `www-data`and so the script returns nothing.

As you see I want to use the Package `CoolProp`.

1. So I tried installing it with `pip install CoolProp`=> That works for my local user. But now when called from user `www-data`
2. After I tried to install it with a target `--target=/usr/local/lib/site-packages/` but that did not help.
3. I tried to change the ACL on the complete `site-packages/` to `rwx`
   for www-data but that does not work as well.

**In the end:** What is the simplest way to `pip install` a package that can be used by all users including `www-data`?

Comment: To add on this: Today I would do it completely different:
1) I would not call a python script from PHP but rather create a small python app (e.g. with [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/)) and deploy it as a wsgi app
2) The latter approach perfectly supports [pipenv](https://docs.pipenv.org/) / virtual environments that bring their own package environment.

Answer (score 16):

I recommend that you try the solution that **xotihcan** posted first as that is the easy way to make **most** python modules available to all users including www-data.  However it doesn't work for **every** python module.  If that doesn't work for you or you just want to install modules for the www-data user only then use the following commands:

```
sudo mkdir /var/www/.local
sudo mkdir /var/www/.cache
sudo chown www-data.www-data /var/www/.local
sudo chown www-data.www-data /var/www/.cache
sudo -H -u www-data pip install CoolProp
```

I had this same issue trying to make the Python pyro4 module available for the www-data use.  There is another way to do it but it involves some even dirtier hackery.  For more details check out my question/answer @ [How do I properly call a Python Pyro client using PHP and Apache web server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41516827/how-do-i-properly-call-a-python-pyro-client-using-php-and-apache-web-server)

Answer (score 7):

Run PIP with root user.

That should fix the problem.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work.  This might install the modules for user `root` but not anybody else.

Comment: @infinigrove Did you try it? Because that's not how pip works. When run as root, it installs the module in the system `site-packages` directory, making it accessible to anyone using that Python installation, unless you specify the `--user` option.

Comment: @David Z I just tried it for the CoolProp module and my bad, in this case it does work. However, in my case for pyro4 it did NOT work.  Interesting.