# FPDF ImportError: No module named fpdf

Tags: php, python, python-2.7, ubuntu-16.04, lighttpd

I'm trying to run a python script from PHP. The python script reads the contents from a text file and creates a PDF accordingly. When I run the `Python` script from terminal, it works perfectly and I get the required PDF as expected. But when I try to run the python script from PHP it gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/amogh/server/test.py", line 3, in from fpdf import FPDF ImportError: No module named fpdf
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec("/home/amogh/server/test.py 2>&1");
echo $output;
?>
```

Python code:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

from fpdf import FPDF
fp =  open('downloads/boot.txt', 'r')
pdf = FPDF()
pdf.add_page()
pdf.set_font('Arial', '', 11)
line = fp.read() 
pdf.multi_cell(200, 5, line, 0, 1)
pdf.output('test.pdf', 'F')
```

I've installed `fpdf` using this command:

```
pip install fpdf
```

I'm running my PHP files on `lighttpd` server. Can anyone tell me where am I going wrong?

Comment: @Pynchia yes, I've tried that as well. Still gives me the same error

Comment: Have you tried to check which python interpreter is used when calling directly from the terminal and when running through PHP? Next step would be to compare the content of `sys.path` for both ways of execution

Comment: @FlyingTeller Both the ways (PHP script as well as Terminal) show the same path `/usr/bin/python`. I also compared the contents for `sys.path`, they are all same

Comment: When running a python script with `import fpdf: print(fdpf.__file__)`, what does it print? Is the path listed also in the `sys.path` when you are running a python script using php?

Comment: @FlyingTeller the paths seem to be same.. My code works now.. I changed the user in my server from `www-data` to `amogh`

Comment: what was the path? If switching users solved the issue, then the folder was probably not accessible for the other user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be because of the different users running the script. I think that when you run it from php it is executed as user www-data

Maybe you ran pip from a virtualenv or for some other reason www-data user doesn't have access to fpdf module.

Edit:

Useful links from the comments:

[How to install Python Package for global use by all users (incl. www-data)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39471295/how-to-install-python-package-for-global-use-by-all-users-incl-www-data)

http://nocurve.com/2018/04/23/running-python-script-from-php-as-www-data/

Comment: If that's the case then how do I change the user of fpdf module to `www-data`?

Comment: I think one possibility could be to log in as www-data user in a terminal and run pip install fpdf

Check this links, they seem related:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39471295/how-to-install-python-package-for-global-use-by-all-users-incl-www-data

http://nocurve.com/2018/04/23/running-python-script-from-php-as-www-data/

Comment: It worked! changed the user in my server.. thank youu :D

Comment: Excellent! Can you mark the answer as correct? Someone downvoted it but it is correct.