# How to resolve: ImportError: cannot import name 'HttpNtlmAuth' in python3 script?

Tags: python-requests, python-3.6

I have installed both requests and requests_ntlm modules using "sudo python3 -m pip install requests" (and requests_ntlm respectively) and both installs were successful.

When I then attempt to do "from requests import HttpNtlmAuth", I get an error stating "cannot import name 'HttpNtlmAuth'. I do not get this error on my "import requests" line.

When I do a "sudo python3 -m pip list", I see both are installed and are the latest versions.

I've not encountered this error before, only "cannot import module", so I'm unfamiliar with how to resolve this.

EDIT 1: Additional information. When I run this script from command line as "sudo", it works. Because I am running my python script from within a PHP file using "exec", I don't particularly want to run this as a root user. Is there a way around this, or possibly running the exec statement with sudo?

Comment: On to something! So I noticed that when I run my script with "sudo", it works fine. The way I run my script is from within a PHP file. Is it normal to have to run this as "sudo"?

Comment: Not sure, but if you are running it from a PHP file maybe it is being execued by www-data user, or other depending on your configuration. In that case maybe you need to install the modules for that user, or ensure it has access. Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39471295/how-to-install-python-package-for-global-use-by-all-users-incl-www-data

Also, is php using python3 to run the script? maybe it is using python2.

Comment: You should not need to run sudo if you are using a virtual env and you should use a virtual env to isolate any upgrades to one app.  `python3 -m venv /tmp/ve` will install the env in /tmp/ve you then use `/tmp/ve/bin/pip install requests`  your app will have no problems doing it this way. PS to run a script with this ve `/tmp/ve/bin/python myscript.py` or you can include `#!/tmp/ve/bin/python` in your script's shebang line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the HttpNtlmAuth class is in the requests_ntlm package so you'll need to have:

```
import requests
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth
```

Then you'll be able to instantiate your authentication

```
session = requests.Session()
session.auth = HttpNtlmAuth('domain\\username','password')
session.get(url)
```